# What is this equation, written on a wall?

Tags: acceleration, laplace-transform

I've also asked this in [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273843/what-is-this-equation-written-on-a-wall), but since the equation in question is related to acceleration and physical phenomenon, I figure this is also a good place.

---

I was asked to ID the following, but can't figure out what it's for. Laplace Transform of acceleration (*x double-dot*)?

[image: Original EQ]

*(Sorry that I can't provide a sharper image - this is all I have access to)*

I don't recognize the infinite sum, and there are some squiggles around the `r` in the denominator that I can't quite make out.

I tried to transcribe it, but since I'm not entirely sure what's going on in the denominator, I can't be certain it's accurate.

[image: Transcribed]

It seems odd to me to see a negative exponent in the denominator, and it's confusing using `i` as a counting variable.

Thanks in advance.

**Context**

There is none. This was sent to me by a friend, off of a "what is this" site. No known artist, location, date, etc.

**Edit #1**

It seems that the double closed integral is from `infinity` to `phi`. But still not much help.

**Edit #2 - Re-done Equation with "knowns"**

Based on some comments, and things not previously seen/added to original transcribed equation, I've got the following:

[image: Re-done]

The changes aren't substantial. The coefficient for the `r'` in the denominator has been proposed as being `n`, or `2`. Additionally, having stared at this a bit longer, the two `2` exponents could also be sloppily-written thetas. Probably not.

All-in-all, it seems that this is most likely trolling.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about physics.

Comment: Why do you think the equation *relates to acceleration and a physical phenomenon*?

Comment: @sammygerbil I suppose an odd usage of variables, by the original artist, could mean otherwise. That being said, I've yet to see an *x double-dot* that was anything other than acceleration. The dots above the `x` are not just to represent derivatives, but more specifically *derivatives with respect to time*. The second derivative of `x` wrt time is: acceleration. Acceleration, position, radii of curvature (i.e. `r`), all point to physics.

Comment: The comment by Willie Wong in MathOverflow seems to me the best interpretation (https://xkcd.com/356/).

Answer (score 3):

This is non-sense (or perhaps 'art-work'). You have an integral on x and yet x appears on the LHS. Probably the artist had too much to drink...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. I was also looking into Lagrangian, but nothing came up (maybe they write all their "L" characters like that?). Also, what you've posted is definitely a comment, and not an answer or solution. In the future, an opinion should be a direct comment to the question at hand.

Comment: I changed 'looks like non-sense' to 'is non-sense' and it has now become an answer. I was being polite by saying it looks like non-sense.

Comment: x doesn't appear on the LHS.  L(x'') appears on the LHS, which is not x but a function of the second derivative of x.  It's perfectly normal to write something like f(x) = integral(x dx) anyway.

Comment: @Joshua $x$ on the RHS is a dummy variable (in your equation and that in the photo), it disappears when the definite integral is performed. The argument of the RHS is $\phi$, not $x$.

Comment: don't drink and derive

Comment: @Joshua See Edit #1. In the photograph the upper limit of the integral is $\phi$. Although, perhaps this is intended to be the golden ratio rather than a variable angle. The LHS should also depend on $r'$ and $n$.